# How to convert negative decimal to negative time in excel and show it

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conversion, format

I'm creating a spreadsheet for dispatch staff to track how far ahead/behind they are of schedule.
Columns C4-16, E4-16 and F4-16 are lists
D4-16 & G4-16 are converting the time from there adjacent columns to decimal

H4-16 is intended to display "Yes" if the trucks are ahead of schedule or ontime "No" If they're behind and "" if nothing is entered. `=IF(I4/24<0,"Yes",IF(I4/24>0,"No",IF(I4/24=0,"")))`
 I4-16 is achieved by the subtraction of columns G - D 
 J4-16 is intended to show time behind "+" and Time ahead "-" by converting I4-16 from decimals to time the formula is `=IF(I4/24<0,I4/24,IF(I4/24>0,I4/24,IF(I4/24=0,"")))` and the Cell Format `+h:mm:ss;-h:mm:ss;h:mm:ss` .
 I receive error of "#############" on negative time

I've attached a screenshot of the spreadsheet

[Negative Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONhgz.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This simple method solves the issue:**

[image]

*To get results in valid TIME format, I would like to suggest subtract TIME values instead if Decimal.*

- Formula in Cell `T51 & fill it down.`

  ```
  =IF(R51-P51<0, "-" & TEXT(ABS(R51-P51),"hh:mm"), R51-P51)
  ```
- Applied Cell Format on `T51:T52` is `hh:mm`.

**N.B.**

- If you subtract decimal representation of TIME, are in `Q` & `S` Columns, you get `4:00` & `-04.00`.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Thankyou Rajesh,  This helps a lot

Comment: Gld to help you @JarnDechert ,,   keep asking ☺

Answer (score 2):

I actually found an answer to this question if you navigate to **File > Options > Advanced > When Calculating in this Workbook**. Check the box with *"Use 1904 date system"*. 
 negative time will be displayed.

Comment: Yes it's one option to fix the issue +10 ☺